# Best .Net Cms for Social Network development, Orchard or Composite C1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, social-networking, c1-cms

Please, I need advice about which CMS to work with... Orchard or Composite C1. I'm about to develop a social network website, and I'll develop the social network features.

My main concerns are performance, light processing and easy development of new features/customization... probably I'm going to host the website in Windows Azure server, I don't know if this detail helps to decide between the both frameworks, anyway...

Could you help me to decide please?

Answer (score 1):

Composite C1 is based on [ASP.NET 4.0 and LINQ](http://www.composite.net/C1/Intro/For-Developers/Backender.aspx) while Orchard uses [MVC and nHibernate](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Orchard-dependencies-and-libraries.ashx).

Both frameworks have support for Azure.

Both frameworks are fairly new so it's hard to say which framework would be best for your project without more details.

For example: how many users are you looking to support? Do you want ease of development now or in the long term when the project gets more complex?

Comment: It would also depend on what you know too. Do you know how to work with webforms or do you know how to work with the MVC framework.

Comment: this could have been a useful question ... if the same old folks of SO [bla bla bla ...not constructive...] hadn't close it

Comment: Absolutely.  I'm so tired of SO closing questions that are actually helpful.  How often do we see dozens of upvotes on closed questions.  Stop closing questions SO.